# React & Redux - Store updates but component doesn't

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Seen that there are already plenty of those threads, still coulnd't find there anything that could help my case. I bet that this is some mutability case, but I don't realy see where it could be. Every action is dispatched, Reducer gets them all and the store is updated - redux devtools confirms it, still LoginPage component don't get the update, it is only receiving initialState on load/refresh page. mapStateToProps is called only once at mounting. Had the same problem few days ago with different page, but in the end and frustration I rewrote it completely and have no idea what fixed that - final code was same to me, only thing I can think of that has changed is maybe I was accessing wrong field in store.

If anyone care or wish to help, I would be glad.

Code belows:

**LoginPage.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { RoutedComponent } from 'routes/routedComponent'

class LoginPage extends RoutedComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
  }

  state = {
    loginForm: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  }

  onFieldChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target

    this.setState({
      loginForm: {
        ...this.state.loginForm,
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="email" value={this.state.loginForm.email} onChange={this.onFieldChange} />
        <input type="password" value={this.state.loginForm.password} onChange={this.onFieldChange} />
        {this.props.hasFailed && <h4>Something is wrong</h4>}
        {this.props.isLoading && <h4>Logging in...</h4>}
        {this.props.hasLoggedIn && <h4>You are logged in</h4>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps ({ user }) {
  console.log(user)
  return {
    hasLoggedIn: user.hasLoggedIn,
    hasFailed: user.hasFailed,
    isLoading: user.isLoading,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: params => dispatch(loginUser(params))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage)
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  hasFailed: false,
}

export function usersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(state)
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOGGING_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      }
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasLoggedIn: true,
        isLoading: false,
      }
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasFailed: true,
        isLoading: false
      }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

**loginUser action**

```
export function loginUser(credentials) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loggingUser())
    tryToLogUser(dispatch, credentials)
  }
}
```

**tryToLogUser function**

```
export function tryToLogUser(dispatch, credentials) {
  fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}auth/token/`, {
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST'
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText)
    }
    return response
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((tokenData) => {
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', tokenData.access_token)
    dispatch(loginSuccess())
  })
  .catch((error) => dispatch(loginFailure()))
}
```

**and way i combine reducers**

```
export const makeRootReducer = (asyncReducers) => {
  return combineReducers({
    layout,
    router,
    notifications,
    resources: resourcesReducer,
    user: usersReducer,
    ...asyncReducers
  })
}
```

**RoutedComponent**

```
export class RoutedComponent extends React.Component{
    getLayoutOptions() { return {} };

    componentDidMount() {
        const options = this.getLayoutOptions();

        if(this.props.setCurrentPageSettings) {
            this.props.setCurrentPageSettings(options);
        }

        // Apply the layout settings from the ones provided in the URL
        if(this.props.location.query) {
            const urlSettings = _.mapObject(this.props.location.query,
                val => autocast(val));
            this.props.setLayoutSettingsSafe(urlSettings);
        }

        // Go to Top
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}

// Attach restoreSettings action to the Component
export function connect(mapStateToProps = () => ({}), mapActionCreators ={}) {
    const extendedActionCreators = Object.assign([], mapActionCreators, {
        setCurrentPageSettings,
        setCurrentPageSettingsLiteral,
        setLayoutSettingsSafe
    });
    return redux.connect(mapStateToProps, extendedActionCreators);
};
```

Comment: what does `RoutedComponent` look like? Is it a `PureComponent` or does it implement `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: @TylerSebastian added code for it. It seems to work in another component, very alike to this one

Comment: Import like this instead: `import RoutedComponent from 'routes/routedComponent'`. You're currently importing the unconnected component.

Comment: @Oblosys almost - there's not default export either. He needs to change to `export default function ...`

Comment: Good catch, this code is just exporting `connect`. The whole last export should be replaced by `const extendedActionCreators = ..` and `export default redux.connect(null, extendedActionCreators)(RoutedComponent);`.

Comment: Good catch indeed, RoutedComponent is code done by my either my colegue or author of the whole template, seems that I still need to improve my code reviewing and put less faith in others work. I need to look what exactly this RoutedComponents is for, as replacing it with standard React,Component does the trick. Huge thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Przemek Looking at it again, I see now that the `connect` export is on purpose, to be imported with `import { RoutedComponent, connect } from 'routes/routedComponent'`, so disregard my earlier comments. I don't think changing the import will fix your problem though :-(

Comment: @Oblosys no prob man, I have already figured out that it should be used. Still huge thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this.state at the place
 of this.props in your component by assigning props to your component state

Comment: Isn't the whole point of mapping state to props to use props?